# Adobe font Issue for Mobile displays

Tags: html, css, web, fonts, display

I have created a website and hosted, [www.sellrfinance.com](http://www.sellrfinance.com)

The font submit button has no font, the same font is being used and shows but no the button, I have followed every guide on stackoverflow to see why this happens but at no success, adding link in the header, ect, I want to figure out the issue so I don't have it in the future.

Many thanks

[image]

Comment: have you activated your fonts for  mobile ? in your adobe account?

Comment: umm i haven't would it be okay to direct me on how to please?

Comment: i think the font is activated correctly and the issue is in the font weight as i have answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the wrong font-weight given on the submit button CSS:

change `.contact button{font-weight:75%}` to `.contact button{font-weight:400}`

The font-weight should be a number like 100, 200, 400, 700 and not a percentage value..

Comment: I've made the change but it seems to still be blank

Comment: pls add screenshot on your question

Comment: added within in example

Comment: add .contact button{color:#000} property and check

Comment: you're a legend!

Comment: kindly accept the answer too :)